# sqlsrv fetch array is only returning 1 result (most recent) and i know there is 5+ for a particular code

Tags: php, sql

Here is my query, it's only pulling the most recently added HOLDCODE. Armcode is a patient id and Holdcode is a two digit code.

```
$test = sql::query("select ARMCODE, HOLDCODE from ARE.AAS.ME where ARMCODE = 'ADSMANZS01'", $row['HOLDCODE']);
if($test){
  $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($test);
  echo $data['HOLDCODE'];
}
```

do i need to foreach or for loop through the results to have them all echo or print_r?

As usual, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yep, otherwise it just displays the last result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use while loop to iterate the results like this

```
  while ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($test);) {
      //perform your task
  }
```

Comment: Great, that worked well. I figured i was some what close to figuring it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was just waiting for the 7 minutes to be up. =]

Comment: No problem. Cheers. Happ coding.